# newly created SQL user not showing up when querying thru pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have the below python script that queries for list of SQL logins. I already had a few SQL logins that are showing up. However after I created a SQL test login it's not showing up when I run my script. Though it does show up when I run the same query on SQL Management Studio.. any thoughts?

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER={hostname}; \
   UID={sa};PWD={password};")

command = ''.join(['SELECT pr.principal_id, pr.name, pr.type_desc,', 
    'pe.state_desc, pe.permission_name FROM sys.server_principals AS pr ', 
    'JOIN sys.server_permissions AS pe ON pe.grantee_principal_id = pr.principal_id ',
    'WHERE pr.type=\'S\' AND pr.is_disabled=0;'
])
rows = conn.execute(command)
for row in rows:
     print row.name, row.permission_name
```

Comment: you are positive you are connecting to the same hostname?

Comment: @Greg yikes that was it! I was using companyodb01 instead of companydb01. thank you! do you also know if pyodbc supports running admin commands like "create login..." I'm not able to create user when I run my script and I get None as output because such query doesnt usually return anything other than "Success" message on GUI..?

Comment: Tsql is governed by permissions

Comment: @Greg I login as 'sa' but still no result and works fine thru GUI as always...

Comment: @Greg I guess I have to use Powershell for that

Comment: It is successful unless an error is returned.